# Why does 'this' refer to the "Window" object even when using bind() in another object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

I am confused why the 'this' within the function print. This refers to the Window object even when it is bound within the 'obj' object.

```
function printThis() {
    console.log(this);
}

const obj = {
    boundFunction: printThis.bind(null)
}

printThis();
obj.boundFunction();
```

Should not the obj.boundFunction() return 'null' or at least the scope where the function is declared (the 'obj' function)? Why is it not forming a closure with 'obj' or 'null' here?

I was expecting the obj.boundFunction() to print either 'obj' or null. But, it is referring to the Window object.

Comment: It's [right there in the MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#:%7E:text=If%20the%20function%20is%20not%20in%20strict%20mode%2C%20null%20and%20undefined%20will%20be%20replaced%20with%20the%20global%20object%2C%20and%20primitive%20values%20will%20be%20converted%20to%20objects.):

> If the function is not in strict mode, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be converted to objects.

In other words, your function wasn't defined with strict mode enabled.

This information can also be found in the [ECMAScript Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/strict-mode-of-ecmascript.html#:%7E:text=If%20this%20is%20evaluated%20within%20strict%20mode%20code%2C%20then%20the%20this%20value%20is%20not%20coerced%20to%20an%20object.%20A%20this%20value%20of%20either%20undefined%20or%20null%20is%20not%20converted%20to%20the%20global%20object%20and%20primitive%20values%20are%20not%20converted%20to%20wrapper%20objects.):

> If this is evaluated within strict mode code, then the this value is not coerced to an object. A this value of either undefined or null is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects.